# Can't move discussion to chat with scroll wheel

Tags: bug, status-deferred, comments, conversation

I pointed out some problems in an answer, and after a few back and forts between me and the auhtor, the system suggested me to move this to chat:

> Please avoid extended discussions in
>   comments. Would you like to
>   automatically move this discussion to
>   chat?

I click on my mouse's scrolling wheel, to open the chat tab in a new tab like I do for other links. It didn't work. Rather, each time, it opened a tab of the question.

Comment: Your point being it should look like a button instead of a link?

Comment: @balpha: That would be a way to fix it, or may it work like every other link on the planet. Usually, clicking on your scroll wheel opens the link in a new tab. That doesn't happen. It's a tab of the question, instead.

Comment: This is a major pet peeve of mine. Not sure if it's the case here, but many Javascript links on websites simply do not work the way you would expect them to when you try and open them in a new tab.

Comment: hmmmm, I feel compelled to agree with the affirms on this even tho at first blush it seemed like a "no" situation. But I think a button is the wrong approach.

Comment: This is not a link -- in fact you're causing a POST request, XSRF protected and all. After all, with that little click you 're creating a room. So plain ol' "just make it a normal link" is not going to work. /cc @Robert

Comment: @balpha: But *looks* like a link. That's my problem.

Comment: @Borror0: Yeah, hence my first comment. My point is that "work like every other link on the planet" is not going to happen.

Answer (score 2):

Point taken and I don't really disagree; however I see no good way to change this at the moment. We can't make it behave like a "real" link (it isn't one -- clicking that thing causes *lots* of things to go on in the background: Creating a room, importing the comments, etc.), and making it a button isn't really what we want either.

I have one or two ideas I can try, but it's low-pri at the moment.